# mod_vhost_alias on cPanel

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a webserver with cPanel / Webhost Manager (WHM). Now I need to install the Apache module mod_vhost_alias so I can use `VirtualDocumentRoot`.

I've added `LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so` but the .so file does not actually exist. I could download it, but I'm not sure that's the correct way to do it. What is?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recompile Apache to include this file. cPanel includes a shell script `/scripts/easyapache` which will recompile Apache from source and include all the necessary apache modules for cPanel to function. If you don't use EasyApache and install from a package or directly from source, you'll run into issues when the cPanel updater `upcp` runs.

[Here's the official documentation for EasyApache](http://www.cpanel.net/documentation/easyapache/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile it, then that's the best way, that or use a package manager. This is only if you're on a server with root access.

Comment: You're right about compiling from source. But be sure to use `/scripts/easyapache` to compile from source on a cPanel machine, or else cPanel will break your custom modules when it does it's own updates.